# Acumatica - Multiple times Printing of Report Output

Tags: acumatica

I have a Sales Order Printing Report. I have Order Number Parameter. Whatever order number we select it will get Print in PDF. Now only one copy it is Printing. But i need to print same page as two times in that PDF output. 
Can anybody please help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a number view, create a DAC for that, and cross join to it.  Use formula/parameter to restrict
Note I found MUST explicitly cast to an integer, else get run time error in Report interpreter

e.g. SQL Server allows a view such as:

```
Create View NumberView as
    -- This CTE is creating the list of numbers from 1 to POWER(POWER(POWER(POWER(2, 2), 2), 2), 2), i.e. until 65536.
    WITH L0 AS
         (SELECT 1 AS c

         UNION ALL

         SELECT 1
         )
         ,
         L1 AS
         (SELECT 1  AS c
         FROM    L0 AS A,
                 L0 AS B
         )
         ,
         L2 AS
         (SELECT 1  AS c
         FROM    L1 AS A,
                 L1 AS B
         )
         ,
         L3 AS
         (SELECT 1  AS c
         FROM    L2 AS A,
                 L2 AS B
         )
         ,
         L4 AS
         (SELECT 1  AS c
         FROM    L3 AS A,
                 L3 AS B
         )
         ,
         Numbers AS
         (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS NUMBER
         FROM     L4
         )
    SELECT CONVERT(INT,Numbers.NUMBER)    Nbr,
           CONVERT(CHAR(1),'')         AS TstVal
    FROM   Numbers
    GO
```